# llittle endianness of a structure in a structure

Tags: c++, struct, padding, endianness

Given a hypothetical structure

```
struct OUTER {
  uint_16 x;
  struct INNER{
     uint_16 y;
     uint_16 z;
  } inner_struct;
} outer_struct;
```

and a little endian machine, how would the bytes be flipped, i.e. what would the bytes for the outer_struct look like?

Suppose x,y,z = Ox1234; Assume an alignment of 2 bytes.

I'm confused between

34 12 34 12 34 12   // x y z

and,

34 12 12 34 12 34 // x flipped-little_endian_inner_struct

Comment: Why don't you just use a debugger and have a look?

Comment: @HansPassant cause my machine is big endian

Comment: It would look like `struct no_nest { uint16_t x, y, z; };`.

Comment: @DanielFischer so basically only POD's are subject to the byte flips but ordering of the POD's themselves is preserved ?

Comment: The struct itself is a POD, isn't it? Only the integer types are affected by endianness. The order of the members must be the order of declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing little endian flips is the order of bytes in builtin data types. The compiler is not free to re-order the attributes in your structure, and endian-ness doesn't apply to aggregate data structures (only their components). So you'll see `34 12 34 12 34 12` as the result in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The order of structures members themselves do not move based on endianness in the compiler. However, you can't be certain of exactly how many bytes any particular part of your structure takes up or how many bytes of padding the compiler adds between parts of the structure. (I'm not even sure you can rely on the fact that they are in the "order of declaration", but I believe that there is something in the standard about that).